# Undefined array key "name" error after submitting a form for 2nd time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, domcrawler

i've been recently working on a project using Laravel with livewire with the objective of testing the domCrawler componente. my app gets data about products from a store webpage and retrieves the products information. Im working with an array that is loaded with objects of type product.

Here is the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $price;
    public $storeId;
    public $img;
    public $discount;
    public $discountText;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = []){
        $this->name = $attributes["name"];
        $this->price = $attributes["price"];
        $this->storeId = $attributes["storeId"];
        $this->img = $attributes["img"];
        $this->discount = $attributes["discount"];
        $this->discountText = $attributes["discountText"];
    }


}
```

the page uses a form with a textinput and a button, the user types a product name and when the search button is pressed it activates the search function of my controller.

heres the blade.php file for the view:

```
<div >
    <form wire:submit="search">
        <p class="text-green-200 text-2xl">hola</p>
        <label class="text-white">Que producto quiere buscar?</label>
        <input class="" type="text" name="product" wire:model="product">
        <button class="text-green-200 hover:text-red-400" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
    <button class="text-green-200 hover:text-red-400" wire:click="back">Volver</button>

    @if($searched)
        @foreach($productsAnswer as $product)
            <p class="text-green-200 text-2xl">{{$product -> name}}<p>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

After the submit button is pressed the search function loads the array called $productsAnswer with the product type objects:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\HttpBrowser;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use App\Models\Product;
use Exception;

use function Livewire\Volt\mount;

#[Layout("layouts.app")]
class Inicio extends Component
{
    public $productsAnswer = array();
    public $product = "";
    public $searched = false;



    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.inicio');
    }

    public function search(){
        $this->searched = false;
        $prods = [];
        $coto = [];
        $browser = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create()); 
        


        //Coto

        $crawler = $browser->request('GET', 'https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/browse?_dyncharset=utf-8&Dy=1&Ntt='.$this->product.'&Nty=1&Ntk=&siteScope=ok&_D%3AsiteScope=+&atg_store_searchInput='.$this->product.'&idSucursal=200&_D%3AidSucursal=+&search=Ir&_D%3Asearch=+&_DARGS=%2Fsitios%2Fcartridges%2FSearchBox%2FSearchBox.jsp');
        
        foreach($crawler->filter("[class='clearfix']") as $prod){ array_push($prods, $prod); }
        foreach($crawler->filter("[class='clearfix first']") as $prod){ array_push($prods, $prod); }
        foreach($crawler->filter("[class='clearfix first_max']") as $prod){ array_push($prods, $prod); }


        foreach($prods as $prod){
            $crawlerProd = new Crawler($prod);
            $name = $crawlerProd->filter("[class='descrip_full']")->text();
            $price = $crawlerProd->filter("[class='atg_store_newPrice']")->text();
            $img = $crawlerProd->filter("[class='atg_store_productImage'] > img")->attr('src');
            $discountText = $crawlerProd->filter("[class='info_discount']") -> children() -> text();
            if($discountText == $price){
                $discount = 'No';
                $discountText = 'None';
            }
            else{
                $discount = 'Yes';
                $discountText = strstr($discountText, 'OFERTA');
            }
            
            $newProd = new Product([
                "name"=> $name,
                "price"=> $price,
                "storeId" => 'coto',
                "img" => $img,
                "discount" => $discount,
                "discountText" => $discountText
            ]);
            array_push($coto, $newProd);
        }

        $this -> productsAnswer = $coto;
        $this -> searched = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is the app works perfectly fine the first time you search for something:

[it shows the products name good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM3nG.png)

But if you try to search something else this happens:

[some type of constructor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U8wR.png)

i suppose it has something to do with the way i use the array. Maybe it doesnt like being overwritten(?

im out of ideas. I appreciate any help.

I tried to search for a product after a previous successful search.

I expected to see the new array of names show up.

It resulted in a Undefined array key "name" error

Comment: I can't understand why you are using a Model to store your data: a simple array seems more than enough.
Anyway when you ovverride the *__constuct()* you must also call the parent __construct method: `parent::__construct($attributes);`

Comment: In my almost 10 years of working with Laravel, I have never defined `public $name` (or any other attribute that is representative of a database column). Laravel handles all of that automatically when it pulls the Model from the database, or when you create a new one. If you can figure out a way to get this working, I'd be curious, since being able to see the columns from the database table as properties in your IDE would be helpful, but I've never been successful...

Comment: I changed the model to just an array. now it works but something seems wrong. If i search for something that returns 6 products and then i search something that returns 7 only 6 products are shown and the console throws a type error saying: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'before')

Comment: Hi Tim ill let you know if i make any advances, but it seems like the model was a wrong aproach because im not even storing anything in the database at the moment, the product data is not meant to be stored. Now im trying to make it work just using an array.

Comment: Gotcha! I've used a Model for non-database data before, but it requires a lot of work-arounds to get it working, so you're probably better off with a "simple" class, or plain data. Models offer a lot of handy functionality, like `$model->whatever` not triggering an error, but rather simply returning `null` (whereas a simple Object/Class would trigger an access error), and other things, so there are valid reasons to do what you're doing, but I've never tried to couple this with a Form submission, or similar. Interesting question though!

Comment: Try adding a unique wire:key (e.g. *name* if it is unique) in the *<p>* tag into the 
*@foreach:*
`<p class="text-green-200 text-2xl" wire:key="{{$product->name}}">{{$product->name}}<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments posted by Pippo https://stackoverflow.com/users/21380206/pippo
And Tim Lewis https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis answered my question.

Resume
Deleted the model named product and instead used a simple array:

```
$newProd = ([
            "name"=> $name,
            "price"=> $price,
            "storeId" => 'coto',
            "img" => $img,
            "discount" => $discount,
            "discountText" => $discountText
        ]);
```

and then used a wire:key in the foreach:

```
@if($searched)
    @foreach($productsAnswer as $product)
        <div x-init="console.log(item)"><div>
        <p class="text-green-200 text-2xl" wire:key="{{$product['name']}}">{{$product['name']}}<p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Problem solved.